# When can I speak after eating?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, hefsek-interruption, speech-talking

After making a Berachah on food, it is considered a Hefsek to speak before eating said food.

At what point after beginning to eat is it permissible to speak?

After the first bite?

After the first swallow?

After eating (biting? swallowing?) some specific amount?

Comment: It is Asur to talk while eating Mishum Sakana...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'chatchilah one should swallow before one speaks see Mishna Brurah 206:12.

Answer (score 5):

I have asked a Chabad rabbi this question and he said one could speak from the first bite, however, since one shouldn't speak with food in his mouth he should wait until swallowing.